# Postgresql xmlelement query

Tags: xml, postgresql

I've a query:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name Place, Tokyo)
```

and output looks like this:

```
<place>Tokyo</place>
```

how to change query to have output like this:

```
<n1:place>Tokyo</n1:place>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

XML namespaces are not (yet) supported in `XMLELEMENT`.

You will have to do this by some sort of postprocessing, perhaps using XSLT.